# Using strpos to compare against an array

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
if ( (strpos($page,array('careers','employers','specialist-areas','job-search','job-details','job-apply','register-your-cv') == true)) ) { echo ' class="selected"'; }
```

Which is supposed to be finding any matches in the array to the `$page` variable.

However it doesn't work... Am I using the `strpos` wrong with an array?

An example of what `$page` may contain: `"default careers page"`

Comment: Prototype of `strpost`: `int strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )`. Docs about second parameter: `If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character.`

Comment: What if `$page` matches multiple items from the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$array = array(
    'careers',
    'employers',
    'specialist-areas',
    'job-search',
    'job-details',
    'job-apply',
    'register-your-cv',
);

foreach($array as $string) {
    if((strpos($page,$string) !== false))  {
        echo ' class="selected"';
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please put everything on one line instead of two, because it is still a tiny bit readable now.

Comment: Done. I tried and it works

Answer (score 1):

Strpos is for finding string inside string. What you need is [in_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).
EDIT: Misunderstood your question. Here is code that should work.

```
if((count(array_intersect(array('careers','employers','specialist-areas','job-search','job-details','job-apply','register-your-cv'), explode(' ', $page)))) ) 
{
  echo ' class="selected"';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for `$page` in every element of array, so you need some sort of function like this:

```
function strpos_array($haystack, $needles) {
    if ( is_array($needles) ) {
        foreach ($needles as $str) {
            if ( is_array($str) ) {
                $pos = strpos_array($haystack, $str);
            } else {
                $pos = strpos($haystack, $str);
            }
            if ($pos !== FALSE) {
                return $pos;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return strpos($haystack, $needles);
    }
}
if (strpos_array($page, $pages) !== FALSE) {
    echo ' class="selected"'; 
}
```

Also, make sure you don't code like this:

```
if (strpos($page, $url) == true) {}
```

Because if `$page` is at the beginning of the `$url`, strpos will return 0 that will fail your comparison.